# Problema con ngIf y subscribe en Angular

Tags: angular, http, observable

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de actualizar el valor de una variable dentro de un subscribe para decidir si muestro o no un div en el template.
La idea es que si las credenciales de un usuario no son correctas y la respuesta HTTP del servidor no es 200 OK se muestre un div con un mensaje de error, pero no consigo que la variable que se encarga de indicarme si es válido o no, "incorrecto", cambie de valor.
Adjunto el código:

Componente.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { UsuariosService } from '../../../services/usuarios.service';
import { Usuario } from '../../../interfaces/usuario.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  styles: [`
    .ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(form){
      color: red;
    }
  `]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

  //Variables
  forma: FormGroup;
  incorrecto:boolean = true;

constructor(private _usuarioService: UsuariosService, private _router:Router) {

logearse() {
    this.datos = {
      Nombre: null,
      Correo : this.forma.controls['email'].value,
      Hash: this.forma.controls['password'].value
    }
    console.log(this.datos);

    this._usuarioService.conectarse(this.datos)
          .subscribe( (respuesta:Response) => {
            if(respuesta.ok){
              this._router.navigate(['/home']);
            }else{
              this.incorrecto = false
            }
          });
  }
}
```

Componente.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog cascading-modal mt-5" role="document">
    <!--Content-->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!--Modal cascading tabs-->
        <div class="modal-c-tabs">

            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-2 " role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item purple accent-1" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a class="nav-link white-text" [routerLink]="['/login']" role="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-user mr-1"></i> Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item purple accent-3" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a class="nav-link white-text" data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['/signup']" role="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-plus mr-1"></i> Registro</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <div class="tab-content">
                <!--Panel 7-->
                <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="panel7" role="tabpanel">

                    <!--Formulario-->
                    <form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="logearse()">
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                                <input type="email" id="modalLRInput10" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Introduzca su email" formControlName="email">
                                <!-- Errores de validación-->
                                <div *ngIf="forma.controls['email'].errors?.novacio && !forma.controls['email'].pristine" class="form-control-feedback">
                                    El campo no puede estar vacío.
                                </div>
                                <div *ngIf="forma.controls['email'].errors?.pattern" class="form-control-feedback">
                                    El formato no es correcto.
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="md-form form-sm mb-4">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                                <input type="password" id="modalLRInput11" class="form-control form-control-sm validate" placeholder="Introduzca su contraseña" formControlName="password">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Errores de validación-->
                            <div *ngIf="forma.controls['password'].errors?.novacio && !forma.controls['password'].pristine" class="form-control-feedback">
                                El campo no puede estar vacío.
                            </div>
                        <!-- PROBLEMA AQUÍ-->        
                        <div class="text-danger form-control-feedback" *ngIf="!incorrecto"> El correo o la contraseña son incorrectos.</div>
                        <!-- PROBLEMA AQUÍ -->
                            <div class="text-center mt-2">
                                <button class="btn orange lighten-2" type="submit" [disabled]="!forma.valid">Log in
                                    <i class="fa fa-sign-in ml-1"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!--Footer-->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="options text-center text-md-right mt-1">
                            <p>¿No tiene cuenta?
                                <a class="purple-text" [routerLink]="['/signup']">Regístrese</a>
                            </p>
                            <p>¿Olvidó su
                                <a href="#" class="purple-text">Contraseña?</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!--/.Panel 7-->
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Content-->
</div>
```

Servicio

```
conectarse( datos:Usuario ) :any{
    let body = JSON.stringify(datos);
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    });
    let url = `${ this.apptime }usuarios/log`;
    return this.http.post( url, body, { headers })
                .map( res => {
                  if(res.ok){
                    this.crearSesion(res.text());
                  }
                  return res;
                })
  }
```

Comment: Qué es lo que está pasando ahora? Hace algo que no querías? Te da un mensaje de error? Podés ver si hay errores en la consola del navegador, o en el build de angular.

Comment: Simplemente no se muestra el div. He comprobado el valor de la variable y es que nunca llega a cambiarse. Pero aunque introduzca un console.log dentro del .subscribe no se me muestra. No entiendo porqué. El navigate en caso de ser correcto sí que lo realiza, pero todo lo que sea modificar variables o mostrar logs no los ejecuta.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizar el `ngOnInit` en vez de utilizar el `constructor` para suscribirte.

```
public ngOnInit() { 
   this._usuarioService.conectarse(this.datos)
         .subscribe( (respuesta:Response) => {
             if(respuesta.ok){
                this._router.navigate(['/home']);
               }else{
                 this.incorrecto = false
                }
           });
  }
```

Comment: He ampliado el código del HTML, había acortado pensando que sería más claro pero no. Mi problema es al enviar el formulario no consigo actualizar la variable para mostrar el div de error según la respuesta HTTP que recibo.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar la version más actualizada de `RxJs`.

Hay cambios bastante grandes. Entre ellos el uso de operadores como `map`, `do`, `switchMap` y otros.
Lo que en tu servicio sería:

```
return this.http.post( url, body, { headers })
                .map( res => {  // <== Esto ya no espermitido en RxJs version 6
                  if(res.ok){
                    this.crearSesion(res.text());
                  }
                  return res;
                })
```

Ahora será:

```
  return this.http.post( url, body, { headers })
         .pipe(  // <== Ahora los operadores tienen que pasar por pipe
            map( res => {
              if(res.ok){
                this.crearSesion(res.text());
              }
              return res;
            })
          );
```

Reproduciendo tu codigo en [este Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resp-stack-es-183591) pude comprobar que no hay problema. Las variables cambian como se espera.

Si aun así no se ejecuta nada, es porque hay problemas en la respuesta del servidor.